# image location changes in Video in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation

I am using the following code to add an image in a video using CALayer. But the problem I am facing is the size of the watermark and its position changes when I choose a different video resolution. I am making an application like snapchat in which users will select the sticker and add it on the video, by adjusting its location and size.

Can anyone tell me, what mistake I am doing here? or what should I do now so that this will be proper? Thanks in advance!

```
let aLayer = CALayer()
    aLayer.contents = image.cgImage

    aLayer.opacity = 1.0
    //sorts the layer in proper order
    let videoTrack: AVAssetTrack? = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
    let videoSize: CGSize? = videoTrack?.naturalSize
    let parentLayer = CALayer()
    let videoLayer = CALayer()

    let videoScale : CGFloat =  CGFloat((videoSize?.width)!)/CGFloat(self.containerView.frame.width)

    print("sticker frame \((stickerImageView?.frame.width)! * videoScale) \((stickerImageView?.frame.height)! * videoScale)")

    aLayer.frame = CGRect(x: (stickerImageView?.frame.origin.x)! * videoScale  ,y:  (stickerImageView?.frame.origin.y)! * videoScale , width: (stickerImageView?.frame.width)! * videoScale  , height : (stickerImageView?.frame.height)! * videoScale )


    parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat((videoSize?.width)!), height: CGFloat((videoSize?.height)!))
    videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat((videoSize?.width)!), height: CGFloat((videoSize?.height)!))
    parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(aLayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the size of the image as a percentage of the video size. Now your image size is constant. So if you have an image that is 100x100 and the video is 300x200, for example, the image will cover third of of video's width and half of its height. But applying the same image to a bigger video like 1080x720, the image will be around 10% of the video's width and height.

The scale that you are calculating is the relation between the video and its container. You should base you calculations on the actual video size.

Comment: Thanks !, I m able to get x, width, and height using this approach but now only Y is not getting correct, can you please help me?

Comment: @AkshaykumarMaldhure what should be Y?

Comment: it should be the UIImage frame y, how it is kept on the video by the user. he can always change the image position

Comment: @AkshaykumarMaldhure if the X position is working correctly, Y should work as well. If doesn't work it's probably some calculation mistake. Try find it. If you cant, send me somehow all the code.